# Call view in another database in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

1. first Database(Database name : abc )

```
CREATE VIEW sample_view AS
SELECT * FROM  test;
```

There is another database (database name : xyz) on same server so i have to call above view in another database(database name : xyz).

is it possible to call above view in xyz database ?

Comment: If you really need that, it would be better to use separate schemas in the same database. Cross-database queries are a bit cumbersome in Postgres

Comment: I dont want to create the separate schemas in the database, i want to call the view only,

Comment: The only way to do that is a [foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html). But a view in the same database (different schema) would be **way** more efficient

Comment: there  is no another option to call the view in another database